# Collections disappearing values when changing values in dropdown

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-collection

I have a collection with 40+ columns.  Everything works like it should except when I modify the values. When I change the Risk value, the other dropdowns may lose its value.
The screenshot is showing the results after I change the risk value in each row. Even the risk value vanishes when I moved from row 1 to row 2.

I did change the 'Explicit column selection' from True to False and back and it didn't help.

Risk OnChange - Patch(ColGridData,ThisItem,{Risk:txt_risk.Selected})

Thanks

[image]

Comment: If you are using "drop down" control and only saving the exact selected text in the collection, try using this formula: `Patch(ColGridData,ThisItem,{Risk:txt_risk.Selected.Value})`, make sure to use the correct name of your control in formula. Let me know if it works for you.